# Adding together rows from duplicate entries in a dataframe (Excel or R)

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, addition, rows

I have a dataframe that contains some duplicates, around 100 of them, the data is displayed like this:

```
Data                   V1       V2      V3      V4 
Cellulomonas uda      0.2       0.0     0.0     0.1
Cellulomonas uda      0.0       0.1     0.3     0.1
```

But I would like to find all the duplicates in the dataframe and add them together, to give this:

```
Data                   V1       V2      V3      V4 
Cellulomonas uda      0.2       0.1     0.3     0.2
```

Is there a function in dplyr which could help with this? Or even a way to add the rows together in Excel and just manually deleting one of the duplicates would be fine.

Comment: consider `na.rm=T` for `sum`-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the sum of V values  for  each `Data` value :

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Data                   V1       V2      V3      V4 
'Cellulomonas uda'      0.2       0.0     0.0     0.1
'Cellulomonas uda'      0.0       0.1     0.3     0.1",h=T,string=F)

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% group_by(Data) %>% summarize_all(sum)
# # A tibble: 1 x 5
#                 Data    V1    V2    V3    V4
#                <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1 Cellulomonas uda   0.2   0.1   0.3   0.2
```

Comment: `summarise_all(sum)` might be more appropriate for the OP's question.

Comment: This hasn't added them together though. Oh sorry Mudskipper, I just saw your comment. The values are not duplicated, just some of the names in the "Data" column. The values in V1 etc are unique.

Comment: Yes, using `sum` seems to work fine. Thank you both

Comment: alright edited, thanks @hpesoj626

Comment: I think `V4` should have a value of `0.2`

Comment: edited again ;)

Answer (score 2):

With base R we could use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(. ~ Data, df1, sum)

              Data  V1  V2  V3  V4
1 Cellulomonas uda 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.2
```

And with `data.table` I think we could do:

```
library(data.table)

dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Data]

              Data  V1  V2  V3  V4
1 Cellulomonas uda 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.2
```